# Microsoft Graph Exception SubscriptionCountReached

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, http-status-code-429

I am getting this while creating a `calendar` `subscription` using `Microsoft Graph`.
it's throwing this exception

```
 Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: 429; Reason: Resource
 'SubscriptionCountReached' has reached limit of '1000'.  Please retry
 after '12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM']
```

Any ideas about what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means you have already reached your allowed number of requests for your subscription plan (which seems to be 1000, as per the error message), and thus you probably have to pay (or change plan, or have an arrangement with Microsoft, etc.) to be allowed to send further requests without error.

The date being set as the *maximum possible date* (31st December 9999) is usually set in this context for telling that the count limit will not be "reset", you reached some 
hard limit.

For details about the exact conditions of your plan, on how you can change these, or if you think this is a mistake, you'll have to contact Microsoft support directly, as [Stack Overflow is not the right place to get such information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: Are you sure the fields are in the correct order.  That date really looks wrong.

Comment: Only Microsoft could know that. But if this is correct, having an "retry after 12/31/9999" probably means that you won't be able to retry, you had a fixed non-renewable number of requests 1000. They used the maximum possible value for a date to express this, which is not uncommon in various APIs

Comment: @Pac0 can you elaborate more on request limit? I am using a free 30 day trial exchange account.

Comment: @user3198189 I am not a Microsoft support service employee, I have absolutely no knowledge of commercial details with Microsoft, and Stack Overflow is not the right place to request such support. You should contact their customer support directly, as this concerns only you and them. As a guess, the information about various limitations should be available at roughly the same place as where you subscribed to your plan.

Comment: @jdweng and about the order of the date fields, I may see some confusion. This is US date formatting, with month / day / year (MM/dd/yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

**`Error code 429`** means that your `quota of times` you can ping service in the interval that is predetermined.

> For a better way to handle that you can follow this blog
>   [Microsoft Graph/Outlook REST API throttling, best practices](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2018/06/01/gotchas-microsoft-graphoutlook-rest-api-throttling-best-practices/)

try to `reduce the amount` of the requests sent in a given time to fix your issue.
Reduce the number of operations per request.
Reduce the frequency of calls.
Avoid immediate retries, because all requests accrue against your usage limits.
Reduce the number of GET call for single items.

> [Error 429 – Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in X seconds.](https://veenstra.me.uk/2018/07/16/microsoft-flow-error-429-rate-limit-is-exceeded-try-again-in-x-seconds/)

Comment: I understand 429, i am concerned about this message "'SubscriptionCountReached' has reached limit of '1000'".

Comment: see yellow marked blog link in my answer it's coming because you reached the limit in which it also defined how you can use that in a better way